# Where is all_queue_subscribers dictionary view on oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle, message-queue, oracle9i, data-dictionary

11g and 10g both have the `all_queue_subscribers` (and `user_`, `dba_`) dictionary tables for listing the subscribers to queues, but this doesn't exist on 9i. Does the same concept of queue subscribers exist on 9i databases, and where can I get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

In 9i the interface was not as friendly.  Each queue table had its own view, in the format `AQ$<queue_table_name>_S`.  This is explained in the documentation.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qadfacev.htm#43232).